# How to pass a function as a parameter?

Tags: c, function-pointers

How is it possible to give a function (B) a function (A) as a parameter?

So that I can use function A in the function B.

Like the Variable B in the following example:

```
foo(int B) { ... }
```

Comment: `function pointer` is the thing you're looking for, but be warned: It's a bit messy and in my opinion not suitable for beginners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write function pointer type in another function's parameter list looks a little weird, especially when the pointer is complicated, so typedef is recommended.

*EXAMPLE*

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int func(int a, int b);

int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }

int operate(int a, int b, func op)
{
    return op(a, b);
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", operate(3, 4, add));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1: interesting - today I learned something - I never knew that you could use that syntax - I've only ever used explicit function pointers, e.g. `typedef int (*func)(int a, int b);`

Comment: yeah. that is designed to simply the usage of function pointer.

Answer (score 4):

By using *function pointers*. Look at the `qsort()` standard library function, for instance.

Example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int op_add(int a, int b)
{
  return a + b;
}

int operate(int a, int b, int (*op)(int, int))
{
  return op(a, b);
}

int main(void)
{
  printf("12 + 4 is %d\n", operate(12, 4, op_add));

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Will print `12 + 4 is 16`.

The operation is given as a pointer to a function, which is called from within the `operate()` function.

Comment: I would suggest not using "operator" as a variable name to avoid confusion with actual operators in C++. But of course it is valid C.

Comment: @stefan I normally don't care much about keeping my C valid C++, but sure, why not. I renamed the argument, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you have a function you want to call:

```
void foo() { ... }
```

And you want to call it from `bar`:

```
void bar(void (*fun)())
{
    /* Call the function */
    fun();
}
```

Then `bar` can be called like this:

```
bar(foo);
```